Is it possible consolidate multiple Azure subscription invoices into one?
If I have Billing account type: Microsoft Online Services Program that has multiple subscriptions, one invoice per subscription is being generated at the moment. Is it possible to consolidate these invoices one per each subscription into one?
The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/mca-section-invoice mentions creating a billing profile. However, it appears that's not available for this billing account type. But I wonder if this really is the case that I'm doomed to handle multiple invoices whereas just one could suffice.

Can you share the code tried so far. @Veksi

Thanks for taking interest, but I solved the issue. Apparently I'd need to change the account type.

So, the case is such that I have MOSA type account and I should switch over to a 'customer agreement' one to be able to create billing profiles and consequently to combine invoices/receipts from multiple subscriptions into one. More information at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/news/from-mosa-to-microsoft-customer-agreement.
